# MySQL 5.7 move table

Tags: mysql

I want to copy a few large production tables from a cold backup to a development server, both are on MySQL 5.7.18.  When reading "Moving or Copying InnoDB Tables" for MySQL Server 5.7, I looked at the option for Cold Backup.

Is this the correct process to do on the development server?  Table definition and datadir is same on both servers and Cold Backup was done using a a Slow Shutdown (innodb_fast_shutdown=0).

```
  ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISCARD TABLESPACE;
  Copy .ibd files from backup
  ALTER TABLE tbl_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

The reason I ask is that the online documentation state that you need a, "“clean” .ibd file backup".  Is a slow shutdown clean enough or not?  During the Cold Backup, there may have been transactions uncommitted, but I believe a slow shutdown will deal with all that before shutting the service down?